# Cursor Jump on Dell Inpsiron Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, dell, synaptics

I switched to Ubuntu from dual boot Linux Mint and Windows 10 and in Linux Mint I had to install synaptic touch-pad driver to stop the cursor from jumping. I have reinstalled the driver and libinput keeps prioritizing itself higher, and when I inserted the "Option Ignore" into the gedit libinput touch-pad, all peripherals stop working other than the touch-pad. My specific computer is a Dell Inspiron 11 3179 (not certified to work on Ubuntu) and this is not a "death-con" problem but is annoying nevertheless. Xinput shows it being a synaptic device, but still uses libinput, which does "work" better then synaptic but the cursor jump is annoying. I do have some experience with the command line and gedit as well, any help is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time. 
(edit) It has come to my attention that this is a large problem with Dell and libinput but all posts I have seen have no solutions. 
(edit) The problem is worse than I thought, I realised I was still in Wayland and the touchpad no longer works in Ubuntu, working on a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to uninstall libinput, reinstall it, install synaptics, restart immediately, now I have two devices however, but the synaptics seems to be priority, now how to disable libinput for touchpad. This appears to be working currently, I do not know why I had to uninstall libinput but my exact steps are, login to Ubuntu Wayland (login as another user option), uninstall synaptics if one has it installed, uninstall libinput with {sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput}, reinstall libinput with {sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput}, install synaptics with {sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics} and restart immediately afterwards. After restarting one needs to switch out of Wayland by login as another user. This worked for me after lots of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 18.04. Solved 
Do next
- Open Synaptic
- Search **libinput** provided packs
**- Install xserv-org-input-libinput.... 18.04.1**

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 18.04.  I  was ready to throw my Dell Inspiron 3482 out of the window for this problem of cursor jumping, when my 20 hundredth perusal of the settings finally guided me to the solution: go to settings, select 'Mouse and Touchpad.' Under 'Enable this device' you'll see 'Buttons and Feeback' and 'Touchpad'.  Select 'Touchpad'.  Check the box 'Disable touchpad while typing' and UNCHECK the box 'Tap touchpad to click'.  This has solved my cursor jumping dilemma, and didn't require any uninstalls or re-installs.  Hope it works for you, because this was so simple of a fix.